# My App keeps crashing after splash screen only on real devices, works perfectly on various virtual devices

Tags: android, splash-screen

My app was running fine on all devices but after adding a splash screen, it crashes on a real device (the splash screen loads fine and then crashes the app) whereas on the virtual device nothing goes wrong. I assume something must be wrong in my splash screen code.

```
public class Launcher extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);
        final ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.launcher_logo);
        final ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.launcher_compass);
        final ImageView iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.launcher_slogan);
        final Animation an1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.rotate);
        final Animation an2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.abc_fade_out);
        final Animation an3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.abc_fade_in);


        iv1.startAnimation(an1);
        an1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                iv2.startAnimation(an2);
                iv3.startAnimation(an3);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        an3.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: What error do you receive in the console?

Comment: can you try `Launcher.this` instead of getBaseContext()?

Comment: im gonna guess its an out of memory error

Comment: every thing seems fine in splash screen, check your next activity, if it is a out of memory exception most probably you are using a image from gallery without compressing it, please upload your logcat.

Comment: thing is I am testing it on a huawei p8 lite with 2 gb ram whereas my virtual devices only have 1 gb yet work.

Comment: Problem is I cant connect phone as usb device because there is no oem for huawei p8 lite. and cant seem to find the crash logs in my phone.

Comment: unfortunitly Launcher.this does not make a difference

Comment: also the app worked without the splash screen so im not sure if the other activity is the problem

Answer (score 0):

How big are those images in your imageviews? I have had similar issues where the images aren't too big (IMO) but they end up crashing the app. Check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8205044/742197

it has helped me in the past. Unfortunately, without the logcat it is hard to know what the real issue is but it is worth a try. If that doesn't work, try removing everything, and adding things back one at a time to find out what the issue is.

Comment: images are below 20kb

Comment: I managed to get my phone to work with usb debugging and nothing goes wrong when running the app it just crashes with no log