# How to measure page content length on Android webview object?

Tags: android, webview, measure

I want to load url to embed webview on my app, and measure downloading byte size on webview.  Can anybody tell me how to get the page size before downloading it from embedded webview. How to measure page content length bytes size?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983420/790439) answer for how to find `Content-length` which is the size of the download. But also note that you can't accurately measure this size if your loading a web page because the page might include css, javascript and/or images, whose size you can only find once you know their urls. This means you have to parse the webpage, which means you have to download it first.