# Android: how to get file size before download?

Tags: android, http, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know the size of a file before downloading it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983073/how-to-know-the-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-it)

I must download some pdf in my app.

I need to have the filesize before start to download, to show a progress bar, or to notify the user with the standard 'downloading .. ' notification

How to get a file size having a new Url('http://mysite.net//mypdf.pdf') ?

Comment: Your question has been already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983073/how-to-know-the-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-it

Comment: @Niek You get the content length header and hope it's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
final int length = connection.getContentLength();
```

Try using [`URLConnection.getContentLength`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) as above. If the server doesn't specify a length, then you can't know.

Comment: gives android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @SagarPujari that has everything to do with your code and not the snippet above; you are attempting to do blocking network I/O in the context of the application's main UI thread. consider using an [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html] to offload the work to run in a background thread