# Picasso - does the resize happen before the image is downloaded

Tags: android, picasso

Using this code:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).resize(60, 60)
```

Does Picasso resize the image before it is downloaded?  If the image was 8MB - I wouldn't want it to be downloaded then resized.

I couldnt find the answer anywhere but maybe it is obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, obviously it doesn't resize it before downloading - it's impossible. Look at the chaining, first - download, second - resizing. If you want to get a smaller images, you should ask for a smaller images if you have such a chance, of course. You can write graceful degradation: if the file size is bigger than limit, then just don't download it and display some placeholder instead. It can be implemented by checking content length at first:

```
URL url = new URL("http://server.com/file.png");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

Taken from here [How to know the size of a file before downloading it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983073/how-to-know-the-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-it)

Comment: Thanks I guess I thought you could decode the stream to a certain size on the fly.  Do you know if there is a way for Picasso to accept an Array of Bitmaps instead? Rather than URLS?

Comment: @user3437721 afaik you have to load images one by one using the same `load` method, but by providing path to image or it's id http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/index.html It can be done via loop