# Limit max image file size with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I'm loading images from external URLs with Picasso. To prevent someone from hosting huge files that would hang my app I would like to set a max image file size before downloading it.

Is there a way in Picasso to limit the file size? If no, what's an alternative?

Comment: Why would that hang your app?

Comment: By hanging the app I'm not saying the UI would hang. But all subsequent unloaded images might "hang" and never download, thus breaking my app.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to provide your own OkHttpClient to Picasso (via its Builder) to handle that. Generally speaking you'll need to issue a request to the server to figure out the size of the image and only then decide if you want to get it or not. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35332187/1001542) for more details.

Comment: I was aware of this thread but wasn't aware I can supply an Okhttp instance. Found that it requires an implementation of `Downloader`. I will try this route, thanks :)