# Get file size from url

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection, filesize, http-status-code-302

I having a problem with this URL [url](http://songolum.com/file/ppdVkTxqhwcJu-CAzCgtNeICMi8mHZnKQBgnksb5o2Q/Ed%2BSheeran%2B-%2BPerfect.mp3?r=idz&dl=311&ref=ed-sheeran-perfect)
 its a 302 url and it redirects to this site when you run in brwoser http://mp3goo.io/ but when you post this on a download manager it shows 10 mb file and i downloaded and worked fine. And i checked with my android code it says -1 content length  how to get the file size like download manager
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0E6s.png)

Comment: I think this answers the question better, as it supports larger file sizes than what Integer allows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12271781/878126

Answer (score 9):

use this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      URL myUrl = new URL(url);
      URLConnection urlConnection = myUrl.openConnection();
      urlConnection.connect();
      int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
      Log.i("sasa", "file_size = " + file_size);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

That will definitely work for you,

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://YOUR_URL_HERE");
                    int fileLength = url.openConnection().getContentLength();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }         
        }
```

Comment: Content length is -1 is getting for this url it’s a very different url

Comment: is this full (http://mp3goo.io/) URL?

Comment: This link http://songolum.com/file/ppdVkTxqhwcJu-CAzCgtNeICMi8mHZnKQBgnksb5o2Q/Ed%2BSheeran%2B-%2BPerfect.mp3?r=idz&dl=311&ref=ed-sheeran-perfect

Comment: How come `getContentLength` returns an `int` ? Shouldn't it be `long`?

Comment: Yes, If you have large file size, you should use 'long'.