# Create a file type for mine to be invoke be my application

Tags: android

1- I want to build a file content with extension say ".ccc" and I want to let any file browser such as ASTRO to open this file by lunching my activity

2- I want this file to be found in phone galary

Can any one help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question has already been answered here: [Android intent filter: associate app with file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension)

I have not tested this, but you should be able to add an icon in the intent filter (add `android:icon` the the code you already have):

```
<intent-filter android:icon="drawable resource"
               android:label="string resource"
               android:priority="integer" >
    . . .
</intent-filter>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

I don't think you will be able to show swf files in the image gallery for now. I may be wrong though, since there does not seem to be much documentation about it.

Comment: @Gavohab remember that there are no carriage returns in the comments (hitting return will finish the comment). Also, try not to reply an answer by adding another answer (it will be deleted). Edit your previous comment or add a new one instead. Also, please consider to mark the question as answered since you already got a working code.

Comment: I have tried to set icon for intent, but it not appear in file browser, Any other idea??

Comment: Please, add your new code to the question, so I can see what you did. You should also consider creating a new question for the icon. Maybe you will get help from somebody else also.