# Android register app to open a custom extension file (also sharing it)

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter, sharing

I am trying to let my app share and handle custom file extension and upon clicking it, it will open my app then I parse it.

I have looked into different ways like [LIKE THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494769/android-custom-file-extension) for example and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension), but clicking on the file from FileBrowser or WhatsApp for example is not detecting my app.

I am using the navigation component if it helps

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it if someone have a working example.

Thanks.

This is some of the code I tried (I am testing with txt as it is an easy extension) (1)

```
 <intent-filter
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_hp_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern="*.txt" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_hp_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/txt" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I also tried  (2)

```
 <intent-filter
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_hp_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_hp_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt"
                    android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_hp_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <!--
                    Work around Android's ugly primitive PatternMatcher
                    implementation that can't cope with finding a . early in
                    the path unless it's explicitly matched.
                -->
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.txt" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.txt" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.txt" />
                <!-- keep going if you need more -->

            </intent-filter>
```

and (3)

```
 <intent-filter
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_hp_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: What extension are you using and how is your <intent-filter> implemented?

Comment: @javdromero I just updated my question and included some of the IntentFilter that I tried, I am currently testing with `txt` extension but I want to be something like `asd` a new custom extension

Comment: I guess you have already tried with just `<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />` and it's not working

Comment: if you mean ``` <intent-filter
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_hp_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>```
then it is not working either, I also tried an IntentFilter with only the data

Comment: File extensions are not used much in modern versions of Android. Focus instead of `text/plain` as a MIME type for the `content` scheme, and forget about file extensions.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have updated my question and added (3) do you mean something like that?
Also if you think I should avoid depending on custom extension, can you please provide an example / link to check. Thank you

Comment: "do you mean something like that?" -- I would also add `<data android:scheme="content" />`, or use that instead of `<data android:scheme="file" />`. You will not get `file` `Uri` values on modern versions of Android. "if you think I should avoid depending on custom extension" -- `.txt` is not very custom, and it is tied to a well-known MIME type. If what you are *really* trying to do is a custom MIME type, that will mostly be practical for Web requests (so, `http` and `https` schemes, more so than `content`, and `file` will be pointless).

Answer (score 2):

I finally my issue, I was testing multiple things at the same time.
I ended up using

```
  <!-- this is needed for apps like whatsapp, it doesn't provide extension, so you can't add path  -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

                <data
                    android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                    android:scheme="content" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- this is needed for apps like explorer -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext"
                    android:scheme="content" />
            </intent-filter>
```

If you use `mimeType="*/*` then check logcat (no filter at all), search for `content://` then you see what is the Android sending to your app, then modify the IntentFilter to match what you want. Some apps don't send the extension so using `pathPattern` was not working with it, Also using `schema = content` is needed

Thanks @CommonsWare for the help.

Comment: Your solution worked... but Whatsapp return uri of file without extension how did you handle it?