# Associate file extension to Android app and handle the file

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent

In my android app I want to associate my app with *.bin extension. Whenever a user click on a *.bin file, I want my app to be started and make a conversion. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension) link shows associating process, but when the app is onCreate, how can I get the file, its path, etc?

I couldn't find how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when the app is onCreate, how can I get the file, its path, etc?

Call `getIntent().getData()` in your `Activity` to retrieve the `Uri` that represents the file or URL that you are to open.

Answer (score 2):

Your `path` will be the URI passed from `intent`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String path = intent.getDataString();
```