# Open with my app when I downloaded from Email as an attachment of my own extention file

Tags: android, email-attachments, file-association

I have a custom file which has an extention of ***.tax** which managed by my application which I am developing currently.I could associate `.tax` files any where on the sdcard in android device but when the same  `*.tax`  i tried to open from an email as attachment when downloaded, but it says no proper application found to open this file.

Is there any separate attributes which i need to set in `manifies.xml` file in order to associate my `*.tax` file to open from Email or is there any permissions or things which i missed. plz help me out.

[image]

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension