# Select application to open links with in Android

Tags: android

I want to write an app that allows me to remotely start downloading a torrent on my desktop from my phone. How can I change android to open magnet links with my app? I'm trying to find a non-browser specific solution that can be executed on install without the user having to go through settings.

EDIT:

Something like this?

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="magnet" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/myApp" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I think you'll find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension

Comment: So I should do what I put in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find a non-browser specific solution that can be executed on install without the user having to go through settings.

Im not quite sure I understand what exactly you are trying to do with links. But I can tell you that it probably isn't going to work the way you want it on any stock devices. There is no mechanism within the system to let your application start doing anything right after it is installed. At the very least the user is going to have to choose to use your application to handle whatever links you are trying to override.