# Android intent-filter pathPattern

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make intent-filter which can detect urls like this one:

```
http://192.168.0.xx/playlist/_definst_/iphone.smil/list.m3u8?token=XXXXXXX
```

I tried this so far, but no luck.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\*.m3u8.*"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
```

What am I missing?
Need your help.

This worked for me. Hope it helps other too.

```
 <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u8" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.m3u8" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..m3u8" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.m3u8" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with this,

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern="*.*\\.m3u8" />
</intent-filter>
```

Or, with this

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />        
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />        
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u8" />
</intent-filter>
```

This worked:

```
     <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u8" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.m3u8" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..m3u8" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.m3u8" />
```

Comment: if I removed the dot between iphone and smil( iphone.smil) it works. I think the dot has something to do with it.

Comment: look at this : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12153391/556975] . It shows how to handle such scenarios.

Comment: There's an extra dot on the second to last case, ..m3u8

Comment: 8 years old but what should "This worked" mean? That the other above did not?