# Android intent filter file type http

Tags: android, file, android-intent, types, filter

I registered an intent filter in my application to open the file type ".m3u", it works for the local files selected with file browser , but it does not show my application on the "open with" menu in these cases:

- If I click on a link to an "m3u" file
- if I download the "m3u" file and then click on the notification bar to open the download file (otherwise if I browse for the downloadde file and I click on it my app appears on the "open with " menu.

here the portion of the Manifest file where I set the intents

```
 <!-- LOCAL FILE -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u"
                    android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
<!--             HTTP FILE -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Pecana, I'm thinking about your `android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u"`. Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817296/android-intent-filter-pathpattern). I'm suspecting this will solve your issue.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me :-( I tried with this and other similar solution but nothing seems to work :-(

Comment: Sorry, after some changes everything is working :-) By the way I'm still not able to open the file when i click on the downloaded file from the noticiation bar. What's the difference between clicking on the notification bar to open the file and browse for the file anc click on it? Thank you

Comment: Hi @Pecana, can I ask you please to post your solution and accept it as an answer? This might help others with similar issues (and also helps me to understand how you've fixed it). =) Now regarding your question, I believe you may need to create a `PendingIntent` and set it to your `Notification`. I do belive [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) may solve the issue you mentioned with the notification bar.

Comment: Hi @AuroMetal I understand what you mean , but this is not my case :-) I don't have to handle my own notification using PendingIntent , what I need is abit more diferent. If from the browser I click on an m3u link now I'm able to handle the request and the intent filter is working, the problem is when from the site you click on the link and the browser download the file, on the notification bar the "downloaded file notification" appears and if i click on it to open the file the intent filter does not work :-( Is there an other ilter I miss? content or something like that??

Answer (score 0):

Here the working solution for Local file (browsing with a file menager), http and https :-)

```
<!-- LOCAL FILE -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u"
                    android:scheme="file" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u"
                    android:scheme="file" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.M3U"
                    android:scheme="file" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.M3u"
                    android:scheme="file" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3U"
                    android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- HTTP FILE -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u8"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u8"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.m3u8"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..m3u8"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.m3u8"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.m3u"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..m3u"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.m3u"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u8"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u8"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.m3u8"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..m3u8"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.m3u8"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.m3u"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..m3u"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.m3u"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I'm still looking for a solution for the dowloaded files..

Comment: Did you try these categories: **<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />**