# Android Intent Filter for custom file type

Tags: java, android, intentfilter

## Problem

I have a **zip** file but with a custom file extension **xyz**.
I want my app to be able to open ONLY files with the custom file extension **xyz** from:

- Gmail,
- `Open with` from the android file explorer,
- `Share via` from the android file explorer.

## What I have already tried

My best shot was to just use a mime type of `application/zip`. However this would also open files with the file extension **.zip**.

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/zip" />
</intent-filter>
```

I tried to add a `<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz"/>`. But the problem with this is, that it will be ignored as long as I don't specify `android:scheme` and `android:host` [see here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element?hl=de).

> This attribute is meaningful only if the scheme and host attributes are also specified for the filter.

As soon as I specify the scheme and host as seen in the next code segment, I can't even open any file with my App:

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:scheme="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/zip" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz"/>
</intent-filter>
```

**Possible Duplicates:**

- [Android intent filter: associate app with file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3760276/9641046)
- [android how to open external file with my application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17029001/9641046)

Comment: What you want has never been reliable, and it is completely impractical on Android 7.0+. We mostly use `content` scheme `Uri` values, and there is no requirement for them to have any file extension at all, just as this Web page has no file extension.

Answer (score 2):

Use `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/zip`. Bellow works for me:

```
<intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError"
               android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
               android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:priority="50" >
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:scheme="file" />
  <data android:scheme="content" />
  <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext" />
  <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ext" />
  <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ext" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: not sure why this answer doesn't get more votes. It did work for me. Like a charm. Thx Michael