# How to register my Android App to open my custom file extension, and not for all files

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter, file-type

I'm trying to associate my App with my custom file extension.

[like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension)

I did succeed, but now, **my App want to open for every files**, pdf..., or wathever. My custom files don't have a specific minetype, so i'm trying with different **pathPattern** combinations but didn't find anything working on Android 4.

```
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.custom" />
```

This worked good on Android 2.3.3, but badly not on v4.

What am i supposed to do, to make it work ? Any tips ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Ok i finally managed to make it work better, i'm still not fully understanding how the manifest intent filters are supposed to work, but here is what i did:

**Intent intercept app** showed me the mimetype of my files: "text/plain" so first i did is to add:

```
 <data android:mimeType="text/plain" >
```

So, at this point, my App is not showing for every files anymore.

Then, when i'm creating the file, i added: `sendIntent.setType("application/custom");`
and i added in manifest file the corresponding mimetype.

This way worked good on both Android 2 and 4 phones i tested.

If someone found or wrote something about how intent-filter is exactly working, please let me know !