# intent filter link my app to all files

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have a custom file type with the extension `.myext`.
I've read android doc and many SO posts to understand how to configure intent filter to associate these files to my app. It works but not properly.

When I use this intent filter :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myext" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

then it links `.myext` files to my app, but also every file that has no app assoiated. So I can open `.otherext` file which I don't want.

Then I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097734/575481 which suggest to have multiple intent-filter, So I get :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myext" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myext" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but this doesn't seem to work for me.

What I want is that : my apps opens only .myext files. Do you have any idea ?

Furthermore I will need to open some other file ext (.myext1, .myext2) , but I guess once I get the proper intent-filter, I just have to duplicate it for the others with the extension, right ?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. In my case I am trying to get a .ppp from e-mail and it was fetching any file.
this is the working filter

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"   android:pathPattern=".*\\.ppp" android:mimeType="application/ppp"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

on your activity's onCreate put a breakpoint and check the values in

```
    getIntent()
```

specifically mData should give you what to write for the android:scheme and mType what to write for the android.mimeType