# Intent my app from gmail while opening attached files of custom format

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

This is my intent filter

```
 <!-- For email attachments -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:mimeType="application/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.ccd"
                android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!--  For file browsers -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.ccd"
                android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Problem is that my app is opened when any file with unkown format is opened from gmail(eg: dat, zipc etc). It is also suggested while opening pdf files. I need to only open ccd file from gmail . How is that possible?

Comment: Following link may help you do that:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension

Comment: I was useful..Thanks..

Comment: is it allow you for .jpg format, as i can do it with my file format like .xxx but i also want .jpg to open in my app.