# Custom file type association for android on click on file

Tags: android, file

Heyy guys after struggling over the google .I got stucked on the problem that.

I want to open my application on click on particular file type(.tap) from email and parse xml data from the file and show inside my application view.
I have try all the way over the stack but unfortunately none of them worked.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension) king of solutions.

Comment: Friend that is the only way you can get the intent of the click for a particulate file type. please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension you can make it work.

Comment: thanks piyush but none worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hope this will works

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data
android:host="*"
android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
android:pathPattern=".*\\.tap" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data
android:host="*"
android:mimeType="application/tap"
android:pathPattern=".*\\.tap" />
</intent-filter>
```