# Manifest custom file format opening pattern not well formatted

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an app that open  .blurch file (its own file format)

The file type opening seems working fine but the new IDE that I'm using show a warning on this line inside `intent-filter` section of the Android Manifest that say that pattern doesn't start correctly

```
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.blurch"/>
```

Any idea about the cause of this warning and a possible solution?

Comment: Can you be more specific about this error, or maybe include a screenshot and some context surrounding this line of code?

Comment: It's a line inside the xml of Intent filter, and the error is relative to this line doesn't depend on the rest of the code

Comment: It's a good idea to show as much code and screenshots as is requested, so the people answering your question don't have to put a lot of work into answering it.

Comment: It's a good idea when could be related. but in this case we have an xml line with a formatting error in `".*\\.blurch"/` string, an issue not related to the rest of the code. Put more code than needed is useless and confusing.