# importing csv file to launch android app

Tags: java, android, csv, intentfilter, opencsv

My project has features to export and import csv file into my application

I have successfully completed export csv file into gmail. I can see the attached file in my gmail inbox.

-Now I want to import the file to my app . On click I need to launch my app and in my second activity I need to perform read from the csv file and add the contents to db.

I wish to ask 2 ways of achieving it.

1. Is it possible to long press the attachment csv file in my gmail inbox and show my app in the launch list. ( like in IOS ).
2. If its not possible, then i will download the csv file to my storage. Then from the File Manager folder, I want to use long press -> share via feature.

I want to show my app in the share via feature list.

Upon click , it will launch my app and in my second activity I need to add the implementation of reading the csv file contents row by row and adding to DB.

Let me know how to achieve either 1 or 2 options.

I tried settings action send and category default with mimetype text/csv.
But i cannot see my app in the launcher list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is your answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097734/3703819

use pathPattern: `".*\\.csv"`