# .puz file picker- Android

Tags: android, file-manager, puz

I am developing a crossword application which accepts *.puz* file as input. I tried the following code in  which the application doesn't accept *.puz* file from default file manager while it accepts the  and begins the game  when it is sent through third-party file-managers like ES file manager. Is there a way to make it accept the input through default file manager?

```
 public void loadFile(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PUZ file"), 1);
}

//selected file will be processed here
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 1){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String path = getPath(data.getData());
            if(path!=null&&path.endsWith("puz")) {
                try {
                    PuzzleDatabaseHelper dbHelper = WordsWithCrossesApplication.getDatabaseHelper();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, null, this, PlayActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PlayActivity.EXTRA_PUZZLE_ID, dbHelper.addPuzzle(new File(path),"dilip","",0));
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Format  or Try different File Manager to select file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following `intent-filter` to the relevant `activity` tag in your `AndroidManifest`:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

  <data
      android:host="*"
      android:mimeType="*/*"
      android:scheme="file"/>

  <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.puz"/>
  <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.PUZ"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Add the following code in `onCreate(Bundle)` to check if the `Activity` was started from another app:

```
if (getIntent().getData() != null) {
  String path = getIntent().getData().getPath();
  if (path != null && path.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).endsWith(".puz")) {
    File puz = new File(path);
    // TODO: do stuff with puz
  }
}
```

---

**Note:** File managers might use different methods for finding apps that can handle a certain intent/file. If your app doesn't show in a certain file manager, try tweaking your `intent-filter`. For example, you might need to add:

```
<data android:pathPattern="/.*\\..*\\.puz"/>
<data android:pathPattern="/.*\\..*\\..*\\.puz"/>
<data android:pathPattern="/.*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.puz"/>
<data android:pathPattern="/.*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.puz"/>
<data android:pathPattern="/.*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.puz"/>
```

For paths that include more dots or are in hidden directories. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153391/1048340))

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood - you need to associate your .puz extension with your application. Here is a relevant sample on what to your intent filter: [Android intent filter: associate app with file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension)