# Define Android file type inside file (for email attachments)?

Tags: android, mime-types, email-attachments

I want my app to show up on the Android "open with" menu for files that have my file type, and not for others. But Android does not let one distinguish email attachments by the extension, unfortunately. (For other scenarios it does allow this; see [Android intent filter: associate app with file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Is there a way to specify a type inside the (text) file? In other words, customFile.myfiletype might look something like this:

```
Dear Android, please treat show this file to apps which say they can open myfiletype.
myData blah blah blah etc . . .
```