# Is it possible to set my flutter app as default action to open files of specific types?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've created flutter app that opens files of specific types (documents of variouos formats). Currently my app provides its own file browser, so one can select a document there and open it.

But is it possible to assign my app as the default action when clicking documents at any other file manager? Of course I need to perform this settings' adjustment right from my app.

Is it possible?
I cannot find any information on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter

Also, take a look at how this is done in pure Android. You will need to change Android code, flutter can't handle this himself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097734/3222189