# Kotlin: Associate specific file extension to open 'content' files which have no explicit extension

Tags: android, file-extension

In my project I want to my app to open custom file extension like '**.bla**'

I used the following *IntentFilter* to do this:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This works great but the **problem** is my app appears in the '*open with*' list for any file type -as expected, but I want it to open just my extension.

I can't use explicit extension '**.bla**' because it wont work if I open a **bla** file from WhatsApp, because the file wont have its ordinary path with the extension at the end, instead, it will be some kind like '**content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/03fda30df57e-c5e3a-46ea-6df67-fd23e4a3cb4fe**'

so, I used the **pathPattern** as **.*** instead of something like **.*\\.bla** to make it work

What shall I do to solve this problem and to make my app opens only the **.bla** extension only

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097734/11181028