# Make your app a default app to open a certain file

Tags: android

How do I make my android app the default application to open a certain file type?

I tried to clear the defaults but the option is greyed out, does anyone know how to do this?

I want to make my app open with my `something.whatever` files in android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Register to be default app for custom file type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465429/register-to-be-default-app-for-custom-file-type)

Answer (score 17):

You cannot force this, and you shouldn't be able to. What you can do is make known your app can open the filetype. The user gets the standard "what program do you wish to use" dialog, and the user can select something as default.
If the user has allready selected a default, he/she needs to undo that before the dialog appears (obviously, otherwise a 'default' wouldn't have a lot of effect, now would it?)

You can tell the world (aka: android) that you want to open a certain file type by adding an intent-filter. What you basically do is put in your manifest that an activity in your app knows how to handle the filetype (or website/protocol etc). That's quite easy to find, a random question here on SO about the same issue would be: [Android intent filter for a particular file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension)

Answer (score 11):

This subject has already been covered here: [Register to be default app for custom file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465429/register-to-be-default-app-for-custom-file-type)

Add it to you intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter >
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 6):

### In Android, how to associate file with a different program.

I'm using a "Droid Maxx" with Android Version 4.4.4

How to make a `something.html` file open with a file editor instead of firefox after you've associated firefox to always be associated with `*.html` files.

You have to clear out the default setting for the app that has associated with a filetype.

**Do this**

1. Go to "Settings".  It's in the app list.
2. Under Device, click "Apps".
3. Scroll down and click Firefox.
4. Under the "Launch by default" entry, click "Clear defaults".
5. Open your `something.html` file again.

Once again you are presented with a choice with what kind of program you want to open this file with.

**If you want to associate and disassociate file types with apps indivdiaully:**

There is a third party app called: Default App Manager Lite:

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5hcHBpYXRvci5kZWZhdWx0YXBwbWFuYWdlciJd)

Then you can run the program and manage your filetype -> default app associations individually.

Comment: Honestly, even though the OP said a completely different answer was correct (though he didn't accept it...), this answers the question he actually asked! And the one I was looking for an answer to.

Comment: @Auspex the OP didn't make it clear whether he's asking as a developer that wants code or as a customer that wants to customize his experience,,,

Answer (score 1):

I think in android every app/activity must have some intent actions and categories in its manifest file. In this intent settings only you have to make your app as default.

Even you write default in manifest, if any other apps found with same intent settings, android system will display all apps with same settings. user has to select one of them, there only it provide one check box to make one app as default for next time onwards. If user didn't check it the list will be displayed every time user opens the file.

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent i = new Intent();        
   i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+path), 
       "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
   startActivity(i);
```

The path variable is your path.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force user to set you app as default but you can show user option to choose your app as default

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    try {
        type = "application/pdf"
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        startActivity(this)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        toast("No app can handle this")
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add Intent-Filter in your activity tag in Manifest, so your app can be shown in a list for selectable as default app