# How to set default open with(dialog) option to my android app?

Tags: android, default, android-alertdialog, open-with

I have a file in my devise called test.csv. when i click on that file is opened through my app.how to set default open with(dialog) option to my app in android?

[image]

above is the sample dailog.how to add my app to the dialog list?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872450/make-your-app-a-default-app-to-open-a-certain-file

Comment: @neferpitou i am not finding any correct solution on that link,is there any sample code please provide me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Register to be default app for custom file type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465429/register-to-be-default-app-for-custom-file-type)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. You need an Intent filter

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for response,i checked the above link but not understand. if possible provide detail explanation.

Comment: Look for the one that says `application/pdf`, I think, and replace that with `text/csv`

Answer (score -1):

I think you may want to read the csv file. you could get the csv file path. So see the following.

```
public static void readCSV(File file) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));// your csv file
        reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null; // every time read one line
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

The stringBuilder.toString() is your csv file's content. Sorry for my English.