# NativeScript - How to receive custom file content from other apps

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to create a couple of file extensions that can be used y my app such as:.coin.mrh,.key.mrh.,.tkn.mrh.

The files will contain JSON content. My questions are:

How do I make my NativeScript App default app to open the files?
How do I handle the files?

Comment: This topic has been discussed in this StackOverflow thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465429/register-to-be-default-app-for-custom-file-type

Answer (score -1):

Are u asking can a file be opened by extantion type ??

Comment: This is not an answer.