# Associating a file type with the application

Tags: java, android, intentfilter, file-association

I've seen many stackoveflow answers in the same topic, but all of them (atleast the ones I've checked) suggest to use [intent-filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element) with the [data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) tag in Android.manifest file.

I'm wondering if it is possible to do this in code? Maybe in the onCreate of the activity.

Some answers I've checked are:

[Android intent filter: associate app with file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension)

[Register to be default app for custom file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465429/register-to-be-default-app-for-custom-file-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not possible to do it in code.  The list of file types you can parse shouldn't change dynamically, either you know how to open a specific type in a specific build or you don't.  So there's no reason to do it dynamically, and the system just parses manifests to figure out what apps can open what files.