# Loading a text file from AndroidTestProject

Tags: android, unit-testing, file-io

I have two projects, my main android application and another test project that runs on top of that android application.

I have placed a text file in my android test project, This file contains information xml content. The xml content is what my android application will receive when I hit my server.

I am using the TestCase class in my Android Test Project to test this bit of functionality. Unfortunately I'm having a problem loading the content to into my Android Test Project. Every time I try to load the file into my Android Test Project it does not find the text file. Am I right to say that the only way I can get to that file is by removing it from my Android Test Project and put it in my Actual Android Project or am I missing something that will let me load the File from my Android Test Project.

Details:
In my Android Test Project I kept my file under /res/raw/testFile 
When I try doing

```
File myFile = new File("/res/raw/testFile");
```

I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/raw/testFile (No Such File or directory)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using the TestCase class.

You cannot access system resource when you extend TestCase.  TestCase is part of jUnit not android.

Instead you could extend InstrumentationTestCase.  This would allow you to access the target application's context, `getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()`, and the test application's context, `getInstrumentation().getContext()`.

Then you can access your raw file as follows.

```
Context testContext = getInstrumentation().getContext();
InputStream input = testContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sample);
```

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492076/android-reading-from-an-input-stream-efficiently) if you need help working with the input stream.

Comment: Thanks for the reply to the question. I'm no longer working on that project but that was more than likely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, resource of one application cannot be shared with the other unless you have made it as a content provider or so..

My suggetion is to write this file in some common place like /sdcard//sample.xml.

And read and write permission for both the apps.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Android Gradle Plugin` version 1.1  you haven't to use `Instrumentation` to load file resource.

I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29488904/870674) how to do it with POJO [unit test](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) case.