# Android Studio unit testing: read data (input) file

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

In a unit test, how can I read data from a json file on my (desktop) file system, without hardcoding the path?

I would like to read test input (for my parsing methods) from a file instead of creating static Strings.

The file is in the same location as my unit testing code, but I can also place it somewhere else in the project if needed. I am using Android Studio.

Comment: I tried almost every combination with IOUtils.toString(             this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test_documents.json"),
                "UTF-8"), it always returns null. Probably because the files won't get included in the jar.

Comment: Are we talking about unit tests involving android emulator/device?

Comment: @Android777 I think we're talking about new unit test support introduced in recent version of Android Studio http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Comment: @Frank where do you place `test_documents.json`? assets directory?

Comment: Yes, we are talking about the new unit test support, not involving the emulator/device. I did not place it in the assets dir, because then it gets packaged with the live apk. I placed it in the same folder as the test (java) files.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Depending on `android-gradle-plugin` version:

**1. version 1.5 and higher:**

Just put json file to `src/test/resources/test.json` and reference it as

```
classLoader.getResource("test.json").
```

No gradle modification is needed.

**2. version below 1.5**: (or if for some reason above solution doesn't work)

1. Ensure you're using at least [Android Gradle Plugin version 1.1](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support). Follow the link to set up Android Studio correctly.
2. Create `test` directory. Put unit test classes in `java` directory and put your resources file in `res` directory. Android Studio should mark them like follow:

   [image]
3. Create `gradle` task to copy resources into classes directory to make them visible for `classloader`:

   ```
   android{
      ...
   }

   task copyResDirectoryToClasses(type: Copy){
       from "${projectDir}/src/test/res"
       into "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/test/debug/res"
   }

   assembleDebug.dependsOn(copyResDirectoryToClasses)
   ```
4. Now you can use this method to get `File` reference for the file resource:

   ```
   private static File getFileFromPath(Object obj, String fileName) {
       ClassLoader classLoader = obj.getClass().getClassLoader();
       URL resource = classLoader.getResource(fileName);
       return new File(resource.getPath());
   }

   @Test
   public void fileObjectShouldNotBeNull() throws Exception {
       File file = getFileFromPath(this, "res/test.json");
       assertThat(file, notNullValue());
   }
   ```
5. Run unit test by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> on whole class or specyfic test method.

Comment: It's a nice solution, but it doesn't work always. If you perform run the clean task, and then run testDebug it fails.
Basically the developer needs to know that he must run the assembleDebug task before testDebug.
Do you guys have any suggestion to improve this?

Comment: This solution worked for me WITHOUT the gradle changes by putting the files under test/res/assets and getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("assets/" + jsonFile)

Comment: With AndroidStudio 1.5 with android plugin 1.5.0 place your json file here `src/test/resources/test.json` and reference it as `classLoader.getResource("test.json")`. No gradle modification is needed. Nested folders inside `resources` are working also.

Comment: @joaoprudencio can you make this task depend on a task that is run every time you run a unit test?

Comment: This isn't working for me please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295824/how-can-i-load-a-json-file-from-an-android-unit-test-that-is-run-with-powermockr

Comment: This definitely works and is good - but now I see a "resources" folder in my app hierarchy.  It's not clear that it's associated with test resources at all (i.e. no (test) label next to it like the test java folders are).  Is there a way to "clean" this up? Maybe move the location of this folder? add that label so I don't get confused with the "res" folder that Android uses for regular app resources, etc?

Comment: `Could not get unknown property 'assembleDebug' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.` any idea?

Comment: Incomplete answer. What is `classLoader`? where to place this line of code? what can you do with the return result?. Please provide more complete code. -1

Comment: That's true, but you could at least complete the code with the test method header (so reader knows it goes inside a test), and assign it to an InputStream, or any other object as other answers did. Honestly, I read the answer this morning and had to spend time reading the method signature, documentation, etc. I would expect something more helpful. That's why I encourage you to improve it

Comment: @ joaoprudencio

Commenting out testCoverageEnabled true did the trick for me.
buildTypes {
    debug {
        // testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}

Comment: when nesting resources, use a forward slash (/) even on Windows

Comment: If you get  NullPointerException or NoSuchFileException - make sure your directory is called resources, not res. And here's the way you get this file URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.txt");
        File f = new File(resource.toURI());

Comment: Just in case anyone else struggles, I was confused for a little while because I was adding the folder while in "Android" view of the project, instead of "Project" view. As a result, I'd created it as src/test/java/com.example/resources - it was with all my tests, instead of in the root of the tests.

Comment: To read `./src/test/resources/file.txt` in Kotlin: `TestClassName::class.java.getResource("/file.txt")!!.readText()`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UTF8 string too large, not the best way to do it

Comment: @joaoprudencio only replace "assembleDebug" with "build".

Comment: please can I convert this to a bitmap?

Answer (score 86):

For local unit tests (vs. instrumentation tests), you can put files under `src/test/resources` and read them using classLoader. For example, following code opens `myFile.txt` file in the resources directory.

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myFile.txt");
```

It worked with

- Android Studio 1.5.1
- gradle plugin 1.3.1

Comment: This isn't working for me please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295824/how-can-i-load-a-json-file-from-an-android-unit-test-that-is-run-with-powermockr

Comment: This worked for me, when I changed from "src/test/res" to "src/test/resources". Using Android Studio 2.0 RC 3, gradle:2.0.0-rc3

Comment: worked as expected. But test is getting pass even if file is not avail under "src/test/resources/" eg:"rules.xml", but InputStream results null in this case.

Comment: kotlin: `val myFile = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("myFile.txt").readText()`

Comment: for my case as I need to read it as input stream in kotlin, I use this: `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("myFile.txt")`

Answer (score 19):

In my case, the solution was to add to the gradle file

```
sourceSets {
    test.resources.srcDirs += 'src/unitTests/resources'
  }
```

After it everything was found by AS 2.3.1

```
javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("countries.txt")
```

Comment: I did something very similar (Kotlin):
1. create folder and file at: `root/app/src/test/resources/test.json`   
2. read data like this: `val jsonFile = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.json").readText()`

Comment: After a very long search and many attempted solutions, this was the on that did the trick for me. Thank you so much @ar-g!

Answer (score 19):

I though I should add my findings here. I know this is a little old but for the newer versions of Gradle, where there is NO src/test/resources directory, but only one single resources directory for the whole project, you have to add this line to your Gradle file.

```
android {
   testOptions {
      unitTests {
         includeAndroidResources = true
      }
    }
}
```

By doing this you can access your resource with:

```
 this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

I've been searching for this and could not find an answer, so I decided to help others here.

Comment: thank you Raphael Ayres. This should be the top voted comment. Also, you need to create your resources directory under src/test/, so you'll end up having src/test/resources/...

Answer (score 10):

I've had plenty of problems with test resources in Android Studio so I set up a few tests for clarity. In my
`mobile` (Android Application) project I added the following files:

```
mobile/src/test/java/test/ResourceTest.java
mobile/src/test/resources/test.txt
mobile/src/test/resources/test/samePackage.txt
```

The test class (all tests passes):

```
assertTrue(getClass().getResource("test.txt") == null);
assertTrue(getClass().getResource("/test.txt").getPath().endsWith("test.txt"));
assertTrue(getClass().getResource("samePackage.txt").getPath().endsWith("test/samePackage.txt"));
assertTrue(getClass().getResource("/test/samePackage.txt").getPath().endsWith("test/samePackage.txt"));
assertTrue(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt").getPath().endsWith("test.txt"));
assertTrue(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test/samePackage.txt").getPath().endsWith("test/samePackage.txt"));
```

In the same root project I have a **Java (not Android) project** called `data`. If I add the same files to the data project:

```
data/src/test/java/test/ResourceTest.java
data/src/test/resources/test.txt
data/src/test/resources/test/samePackage.txt
```

Then all the tests above will fail if I execute them from Android Studio, but they pass on the command line with `./gradlew data:test`.
To get around it I use this hack (in Groovy)

```
def resource(String path) {
    getClass().getResource(path) ?:
            // Hack to load test resources when executing tests from Android Studio
            new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource('.').path
                    .replace('/build/classes/test/', "/build/resources/test$path"))
}
```

Usage: `resource('/test.txt')`

Android Studio 2.3, Gradle 3.3

Comment: Great answer (after 45 mins of searching ). It gets to the heart of several issues and makes it easy to replicate the results using the tests themselves. Fwiw, In AS 2.3.1, Gradle 2.3.1, the `getClassLoader()` versions work as expected. I.e. they find the files, both run from Android Studio AND from the command line on my macOS machine, and on the Linux CI server (CircleCI). So I'm going with that and hoping Gradle 3.3 doesn't break it later...

Comment: Nice!  I'm seeing the same resource loading issue here.  AS 2.3.2, Gradle 3.3.  The tests work from the command line but not through AS, due to `build/resources/test` not being included in the interactive classpath.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I only needed to create `resources` folder into `test` folder and put my resource file in that folder.
Then, in the test simply load the file as resource stream with:

```
val inputStream =
        this.javaClass.classLoader?.getResourceAsStream("gallery.xml")
```

[image]

Reference on medium: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/android-reading-a-text-file-during-test-2815671e8b3b

Answer (score 7):

Actually, this is what worked for me with Instrumentation Tests (Running Android Studio version **3.5.3**, Android Gradle Plugin version **3.5.3**, Gradle version **6.0.1**):

1. Put your files in `src/androidTest/assets` folder
2. In your test file:

`InputStream is = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().open("filename.txt");`

Comment: This works fine for instrumented tests. Did this work for you in the unit test (no instrumentation test)?

Comment: @displayname Watch [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70741657/local-test-open-a-file-in-the-assets-directory). I wondered the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

If you go to Run -> Edit configurations -> JUnit and then select the run configuration for your unit tests, there is a 'Working directory' setting. That should point to wherever your json file is. Keep in mind this might break other tests.

Comment: and than use this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(test.json) ? I added the files there, in the root of the project, it still does not find the files.

Comment: This can be used to load files using `new File()` or similar, but it doesn't work directly with the classpath loading method described above.  It's also a bit tricky because each new run configuration needs to set the working dir, and by default AS and Gradle command line like to use different working dirs... such a pain

Answer (score 3):

Step(1) open Android Studio select Project view

Step(2) and create resources directory under test.

Please look at attached screenshot for Step(2) result

[image]

Step(3) put json file into resources folder(`app/src/test/resources`)

Please look at attached screenshot for Step(3) result

[image]

Step(4) Create a common class to handle reading local json files and converting to respective models using `Gson`

Example :-

```
object TestHelper {
    private val gson = Gson()

    fun loadJsonAsString(fileName: String): String {
        val inputStream = javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/$fileName")
        return getStringFromInputStream(inputStream)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun getStringFromInputStream(stream: InputStream?): String {
        var n = 0
        val buffer = CharArray(1024 * 4)
        val reader = InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF8")
        val writer = StringWriter()
        while (-1 != reader.read(buffer).also { n = it }) writer.write(buffer, 0, n)
        return writer.toString()
    }

    fun <T> convertJsonToModel(jsonString: String, classT: Class<T>): T{
        return gson.fromJson(jsonString, classT)
    }
}
```

Step(5) load the json file stored locally in resources directory created in **Step(2**)

```
val GET_USER_INFORMATION_RESPONSE_FILE_NAME = "user_response.json"
val jsonString = loadJsonAsString(GET_USER_INFORMATION_RESPONSE_FILE_NAME)
        val networkStatusResponse =
            convertJsonToModel(jsonString, UserResponse::class.java)
```

Step(6) at the end of **Step(5)** you would have converted local json file into required model class that can be used to write your unit tests.