# How can I load a json file from an android unit test that is run with PowerMockRunner?

Tags: android, json, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am using PowerMockRunner to run my unit tests. I want to load some canned network response json files from my assets folder.

I am using this method to try to get the file.

```
private static File getFileFromPath(Object obj, String fileName) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = obj.getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL resource = classLoader.getResource(fileName);
        return new File(resource.getPath());
    }
```

I call the method like this from my class which has these annotations at the top.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Network.class)

File file = getFileFromPath(this, "mock_response.json");
```

However, when I evaluate this expression.

```
classLoader.getResource(".");
```

It shows that I am currently in this the directory below while running this test.

```
/Users/tylerpfaff/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/data/res/
```

Seeing as I'm in the platforms resource directory, there is no hope of me successfully loading my resources from my project's resource directory. What do I need to do to access my resource directory of my project?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- try to get system classloader via `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`
- Get classloader from the class that has been ignored by PowerMock. By default:

> "org.hamcrest.*", "java.*",
>               "javax.accessibility.*", "sun.*", "org.junit.*", "org.testng.*",
>               "junit.*", "org.pitest.*", "org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.*",
>               "org.powermock.modules.junit3.internal.PowerMockJUnit3RunnerDelegate*",
>               "org.powermock.core*", "org.jacoco.agent.rt.*"

Or you may use `@PowerMockIgnore`.