# Loading images from desktop for unit tests in Android studio

Tags: opencv, android-studio, android

I have written an android OpenCV application and for testing my functions, I need to load some sample images from my computer and save the results back to my computer to see how if the functions work correctly. 
I put a jpg file under resources folder in Android Studio and I could load a file from this folder but BitmapFactory always returns null. how should I solve this issue?

```
File file = getFileFromPath(this, "roi_RGB.jpg");
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

I load the images as :

```
private static File getFileFromPath(Object obj, String fileName) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = obj.getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource(fileName);
    return new File(resource.getPath());
}
```

bitmap is always null.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** reference desktop file in android because it cannot read from desktop. Take a look in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29488904/3673259) on how to use a test resource folder instead.

Comment: I have tried putting my images in resources folder and loading it. (edited in my post). I still get a null bitmap

Answer (score 0):

The test should be written in the AndroidTest (instrumented unit tests). Apparently the Bitmap.decodeStream or Bitmap.decodeFile do not work in local unit tests.