# Read local file in Android Studio JUnit test

Tags: java, android, junit

I am running into trouble loading a local file that I'd like to use in a JUnit test inside of my Android application.

Here is my application structure:

```
app
    java
        demoproject
            MainActivity.java
        demoproject(androidTest)
            ExampleInstrumentedTest.java
        demoproject(test)
            ExampleUnitTest.java
            testValues.json
    res
```

ExampleUnitTest.java

```
package com.example.zach.demoproject;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test public void checkValues() throws Exception {
        URL valuesURL = getClass().getResource("testValues.json");
        File valuesFile = new File(valuesURL.getFile());

        // ... test logic with valuesFile.
    }
}
```

When I run the `checkValues` test it fails with a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at the `File valuesFile = new File(valuesURL.getFile());` line - the `valuesURL` object is null.

I am using Android Studio, with a more or less "new" application.  The only new code I added was this unit test/testValues file to demonstrate my issues.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341744/android-studio-unit-testing-read-data-input-file problem is about test classpath

Comment: Thanks for the awesome link.  I went through there and tried the answer out and wasn't getting it to work - I found out it was a dumb mistype on my part.