# How to get and show content from url by pressing a button?

Tags: android, url, button, show

How can I get and show content from url by pressing a button in android?
The button is in xml, and I need to show display information below.

Button --> information from http://www.bovalpo.com/cgi-local/xml_bcv.pl?URL=1

My wrong code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bovalpo);

    Button ButtonOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    ButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
          Intent viewIntent =

            new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
            Uri.parse("http://www.bovalpo.com/cgi-local/xml_bcv.pl?URL=1"));
            startActivity(viewIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Removed unrelated eclipse tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to present information from link in the same view in which you press the `Button`, then don't use `Intent`, because it gets you to another view.

What you might want to use is `AsyncTask` ([about](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) that would get informations via internet in background, and then present it below button, or anywhere else on screen.

To make a web connection use:

```
url = new URL("http://...");
urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

And to get web data, try code shown in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492076/android-reading-from-an-input-stream-efficiently?answertab=active#tab-top).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your Intent is wrong. Try using:

```
Intent intent = new intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.bovalpo.com/cgi-local/xml_bcv.pl?URL=1"));
startActivity(intent);
```