# Display full screen text from preferences in Android

Tags: android, textview, preferences

I want to display the typical About / Eula text from preferences in Android.

I know that I can create a Layout with a TextView and load the text but being something so usual, I wonder if there's some more standard solution like assigning the text resource to one of the preferences (something like the ListPreference that is specialised) Thanks!.

Comment: You can build a custom [DialogPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html). OR you can start an Activity from the PreferenceScreen: http://www.coderanch.com/t/543114/Android/Mobile/Launching-Activity-Preferences

Comment: Thanks. I've gone on a simple activity as described there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335988/best-practice-to-show-big-text-data-in-an-android-view