# Getting weird data from Arduino to Android via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, inputstream

I want to receive simple data from arduino with bluetooth module attached. I am recieving data, everything works fine, but i cant read it well. Here is arduino code:

```
char incomingByte;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(2);
  delay(1000);

}
```

Here is Android code for reading data from InputStream (BufferedInputStream):

```
mInStream = socket.getInputStream()

public void run() {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mmInStream));

    while (true) {
        try {
            int a = r.read();
            Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(a));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is problem: When Arduino sends number 1, Android should receive it through Buffered Input Reader as decimal value for 1 and it is equal to 49. But i get 2 additional lines in Log, always same values: 10 and 13. How to avoid reading/receiving this? Here is Logcat output for number 1 sent from Arduino:

```
TAG: 49
TAG: 13
TAG: 10
```

Whats wrong? Why does Android app receive last two lines?

Comment: ASCII code of `'1'` is 49.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `println()` does according to [Arduino's Documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println) :

> Prints data to the serial port as human-readable ASCII text followed
>   by a carriage return character (ASCII 13, or '\r') and a newline
>   character (ASCII 10, or '\n').

Use `Serial.print()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen in before.

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on two aspects of the above program.

1. In the above program, two extra tags that are been printed are ASCII Values - `10` for "*line feed*" and `13` for "*carriage return*".
   The `Serial.println` adds a "*carriage return*" and "*line feed character*" to the end of what is being printed. `Serial.print` doesn't add anything.
   So you can use `Serial.print`.
2. Also, for the part of reading from `InputStream`, you can also prefer the following code: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492076/android-reading-from-an-input-stream-efficiently)

   ```
   BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
   StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
   String line;
   while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
       total.append(line).append('\n');
   }
   ```