# How to convert HTML from numbers to words

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here I'm trying to read an HTML file and log it but the problem is every time i check the logs I see hundreds of numbers instead of the actual code of the HTML.
I added the Internet permission in case you asked

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public class downloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += data;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.i("Result is:", s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        downloadTask task = new downloadTask();
        task.execute("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02");
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace InputStreamReader code https://stackoverflow.com/a/2549222/4168607

Answer (score 0):

the response of API is in JSON format.
You must parse JSON response before getting data.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) an example of JSON parsing in java.
Good luck!